# does anyone know how to correct this code

Tags: javascript, function, variables, var, console.log

```
function tipCalculator(nonTipTotal)
{
  var totalWithTip = nonTipTotal * 15;
  console.log(`You should pay {totalWithTip} including tip`)
}

function tipCalculator();
```

It's supposed to print out the statement of the total with the tip included

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals 

You need to add the "$" before the initial curly bracket, so it will look like console.log(`You should pay ${totalWithTip} including tip`);

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to tip 1500% of the bill...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+tip+calc

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
function tipCalculator(nonTipTotal) {
   const totalWithTip = nonTipTotal * 1.15;
   console.log(`You should pay ${totalWithTip} including tip`)
 }
const billTotal = 25 // get your bill input somehow - depends how this runs
tipCalculator(billTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `$` symbol before the opening curly bracket. It should be `${totalWithTip}` instead of `{totalWithTip}`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals